# Math for converting downward compressor to upward expander

Tags: compression

I’m looking to make an upward compressor.  Could it be as simple as making the compressor ratio a negative number OR making the numerator less than 1?

Comment: so i guess this is not about data compression or a codec.

Comment: you don't want your compression ratio negative to increase dynamics, you want a compression ratio between 0 and 1.

Comment: That makes the most sense to me as well.  If you want yo answer it, ill mark it as solved.